# ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture with front camera

Tags: android, kotlin, activityresultcontracts

I'm using ActivityResultContracts to capture images, is there any way by which I can launch my front camera by default?

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture) it is possible to pass extra data by overriding `createIntent` method, can I use that here?

It seems to be possible by using Intent but is there any way to achieve this using ActivityResultContracts?

Comment: You may use cameraX library where you can tell  which side of the camera would be shown. Details could be found here :
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax

Comment: There is [no documented and supported extra](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore#action_image_capture) for controlling which camera is used by the user's choice of camera app.